# noob I am following this python selenium webscraping tutorial /watch?v=lTypMlVBFM4 I don't know why it won't get the title from youtube and print it

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, youtube

I am trying to scrap this site https://www.youtube.com/@JohnWatsonRooney/videos for the video titles.

This short explination does not help with the problem of the code but I thought I would say it anyway. I am doing this so I can get my foot in the door to then scrap other sites for prices on stuff so I can make a program that gives me a link to the cheapest priced product from a list several sites
as well as a ranking of all the other products and there names incase that wasn't the one I was looking for.

here is the terminal output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\PRO\\Documents\\dynamic_web_scraping_test.py", line 11, in \<module\>
videos = driver.find_element("name", "style-scope ytd-rich-grid-media")
File "C:\\Users\\PRO\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\webdriver.py", line 830, in find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})\["value"\]
File "C:\\Users\\PRO\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\\Users\\PRO\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: \[name="style-scope ytd-rich-grid-media"\]
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:180:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:392:5
element.find/\</\<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:275:16

C:\\Users\\PRO\\Documents\>
```

here is my code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
url1 = 'https://www.youtube.com/@JohnWatsonRooney/videos'
url2 = 'https://www.youtube.com/@MyCraftyDen/videos'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url1)
time.sleep(10)
videos = driver.find_element("name", "style-scope ytd-rich-grid-media")
for video in videos:
titles = video.find_element_by_xpath('//\*\[@id="video-title-link"\]').text
print(title)
```

I don't know what to try I did my best looking up this problem before posting. I know waiting for the browser to load the page doesnt work hense the time.sleep(10) in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to find the links of all the videos in the given page, you can use below code

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url1 = 'https://www.youtube.com/@JohnWatsonRooney/videos'
url2 = 'https://www.youtube.com/@MyCraftyDen/videos'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url1)
time.sleep(10)
videos = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "video-title-link")
for video in videos:
    title = video.get_attribute("href")
    print(title)
```

Comment: I am looking to print the titles themselves in plain text but this is also very helpful.

Comment: I got It sort of, I replaced href with aria-label and it gave me the title and date and some other stuff but since the title is arbitrary I know of no way to just extract the views or other info.